# Relation between decomposed stress measures

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

In continuum mechanics a wide range of [stress measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_measures) are used. The two which I am interested in are the [Cauchy stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) and the [second Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_measures). These two stress measures can be related through:

$\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{F}^{-1} \cdot J\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-T} $

Where $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is the Cauchy stress tensor, $\mathbf{F}$ is the deformation gradient, $J$ is its determinant and $\mathbf{S}$ is the second Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor.

The Cauchy stress tensor can be decomposed into its [isotropic/hydrostatic and deviatoric stress](http://www.continuummechanics.org/hydrodeviatoricstress.html) components such that:

$\mathbf{\sigma} = \mathbf{\sigma}' + \mathbf{\sigma}_{hyd}$

What I would like to confirm is that:

$\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{F}^{-1} \cdot J\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-T} = \left(\mathbf{F}^{-1} \cdot J\mathbf{\sigma}'\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-T}\right)+ \left(\mathbf{F}^{-1} \cdot J\mathbf{\sigma}_{hyd}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-T}\right) \neq \mathbf{S}' + \mathbf{S}_{hyd}$

I thought this inequality was true because, if calculated as shown above, the $\mathbf{S}_{hyd}$ term above  <strike>will be a [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) this</strike> but not a [scalar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) and therefore must contain some deviatoric components. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was wrong. For a detailed reference see [here (page 115, eq. 3.53)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XUiqtGbSb8wC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=pressure%20and%20piola%20kirchhoff%20stress&source=bl&ots=UIHyDj4l1-&sig=Yj6sWyjtlmTXfnbVzPmbOF3Az0E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA8daXnezRAhWKcBoKHakkCREQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=pressure%20and%20piola%20kirchhoff%20stress&f=false). The equation above does give the values for the second Piola-Kirchhoff deviatoric and hydrostatic components. Though these do not have the same meanings that they do for the Cauchy stress tensor. What I mean by this is that the 2P-K deviatoric tensor is not necessarily traceless and they hydrostatic component is not necessarily a scalar matrix. This was the false assumption that I had originally made.